# Modulo Arithmetic - Find smallest divider greater or equal to.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, modules

I'm looking for a nice solution to the following problem:

x *mod*(y + d) = 0.

Where x is a positive integer and y is a positive integer smaller or equal to x. I'm looking to find the smallest d greater or equal to zero.

**Example (Looking for d = 3)**:
16 *mod* (5 + d) = 0

**Example (Looking for d = 1):**
16 *mod* (7 + d) = 0

How can I find this d in a nice way? The solution is allowed to contain modulo arithmetic 
(Example: d = x *mod* y).

Comment: I think $x\ \operatorname{mod}(y+d)=0$ iff there exists $k$ such that $x=k(y+d)$ iff $d=\dfrac{x}{k}-y$ for some $k$ dividing $x$. Is this a good answer?

Comment: @Wore I was at this point as well, but now you have to find the right k.

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive I am afraid that any $k$ that divides $x$ will work.

Comment: @Wore I'm looking for the *smallest* d. I'm pretty sure that disallows multiple solutions.

Comment: I apologize for my earlier nonsense-comment. You need to find the smallest divisor of $x$ larger than $y$. This seems hard to do in an algorithmic way and I doubt there is a nice formula.

Comment: @PeterFranek No problem :)

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive OK, I forgot about the "smallest" part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x$ is any number, any formula for $d$ in "$x\mod (2 + d)$" would be able to find the smallest prime factor of $x$. In particular if $x$ is prime, then this would yield a primality test for $x$ by checking if $d = x-2$. Since testing for primality is reasonably [difficult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test), there is unfortunately no reason to expect there to be a simple formula for what you're describing.